# How did Rose catch up to Finn?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi, star-wars-finn

At the end of movie:

> Finn decides to drive into the battering cannon to destroy it. He is driving only forward and somehow Rose was able to hit him. How is that possible? She turned away for a moment so she has a longer way to go.

I assume:

- Finn and Rose has the same v[m/s] which is constant
- Rose has bigger s[m]
- pattern for time for v=const ->  t=s/v

Verdict: She can't hit him. Or maybe she was faster?

Am I missing something?

Comment: You're forgetting the power of plot!

Comment: Or maybe power of love :D

Comment: Power of the Force?

Comment: @Daniel - Or a force from above?

Comment: Nit picking: It wasn't really an "accident", was it?

Comment: Why are you assuming that two different ships in two different states of disrepair have the same acceleration and top speed?

Comment: I skipped acceleration because they were already close to top speed. About top speed: I assumed that they have the same ships model in similar state. So difference in speed won't be big. Even if Finn's ship was in worse state, for me it wasn't looking that he is slowing down

Comment: (Han Solo voice) Never tell me the physics!

Answer (score 70, accepted):

His vehicle was slowed by the (pressure of the) cannon's beam. You see his ship buckling under the pressure and slowing.

[image]

Based on a quick eyeball assessment of his speed, from the point seen below it should have only taken him about five seconds to reach the cannon, yet he's still more than a hundred yards away eight seconds later when Rose hits him.

[image]

---

It's also worth noting a couple of other facts;

- His speeder already looked *trashed* when he sets off. In the brief time we see hers, it seems in better condition.
- Literally the first thing Finn did was slam his ship into the ground at a hundred mph. That can't be good for it.
- She's a Resistance Engineer by trade. Getting top performance out of ailing equipment is her entire raison d'être.

Comment: By the way, there is a concept called radiation pressure to describe why stars do not collapse onto themselves. I don't like to use detailed scientific analysis to describe a universe in which our laws of physics might not be working, but here it fits well.

Comment: Finn probably really suck at piloting.  He is just a janitor Stormtrooper.

Comment: Last bullet is a very good point. They even emphasize it in the movie by showing her telling him how to put his little glidey-gear thing down. Stands to reason she'd know a lot more about how to get the utmost speed out of the things than he did.

Comment: There are many points in the movie (and most movies) where an establishing shot shows a character mere seconds away from a destination, but it takes much longer in screen-time for them to arrive. That's not a particularly good way to measure finn's speed.

Comment: @Knetic - Sure, but he was *really* far away. And they'd only just established his position and speed.

Answer (score 5):

The movie doesn't say anything about this, but in Battlefront 2, those speeders have adjustable speeds. The range is also pretty dramatic, you can go both very slow and very fast.

We also see Finn's speeder start to fall apart while the beam is beginning to activate (the metal guns melt and "fray"). It's not hard to imagine that it lost some power and speed as that was happening.

So perhaps while Finn's speeder was slowing due to the damage, Rose was able to accelerate to her top speed and catch up to him before he hit the battering cannon.

Comment: Which begs another question: how was the metal melting and Finn didn't even get burned?

Comment: @algiogia - Shielding

Comment: @algiogia - film-wise, it's because it makes for a dramatic scene that looks ok if you don't think about it too much:)  in the film, FInn is visibly sweating, but he's in the ship (and behind the windshield, etc) so there is a rationale for him not melting.